# Каким образом можно сообщить приложению о том что файл скачался в WebView этого приложения?

Tags: android-sdk, android

В приложении есть WebView. Каким образом можно обработать в коде моего прилодения факт того что файл успешно скачался?

Я пробовал использовать **setDownloadListener(this)**, однако, метод **onDownloadStart()** не вызывается.
Может быть есть какой-то обходной путь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, может это не то, но для определения загрузки самой страницы можно переопределить WebChromeClient

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

public final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        try {                
            if (progress == 100) {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать запустить `Thread`/`Timer`/`AsyncTask`, который проверяет `WebView.getProgress()`.

Не пробовал не знаю, но попробовать стоит.